# how to set chrome as default browser of easyphp

Tags: easyphp

Guys. how do you configure easyphp to use chrome as the default browser. It keeps using ie when i use local web from the easyphp menu.

I have already tried to configure the apache but cant seem to find the browser option.

Any help would do. Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that easyPHP uses default system browser. I have Firefox as default so it uses Firefox. If you change default to Chrome it should also work.  I don't see any browser setting in easyphp.ini so I believe you cannot change it if Chrome is not your default system browser.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the options as well.
I couldn't find any, so I just created this piece of code.
Hope that helps.

Create a new text file with Notepad and name it like `start-easyphp.bat`
and save it inside the root directory of easyPHP (i.e C:\easyphp\start-easyphp.bat)

Note the file extension `.bat`

Paste this code inside the file you just created:

```
@echo off

echo Starting Server...
timeout 3 /nobreak >nul
start EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9.exe

echo Starting a new session...
timeout 5 /nobreak >nul

start chrome http://127.0.0.1
```

Note: **EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9.exe** should be replaced with the version you've installed on your machine.

If you use other browser like Firefox use **`start firefox http://127.0.0.1`**

For default browser you use **`start "" http://127.0.0.1`**

You can create shortcut on your desktop for quick access.
If you have multiple sites/project on the same local server, just targed
`**127.0.0.1/my-projects/awesome-project**`

Note: `http://127.0.0.1` can also be `http://localhost`